# Clicking a radio button using javascript not working in IE

Tags: javascript, forms, internet-explorer, radio-button

I have a button, by clicking it a radio button get clicked and which will show a hidden div

below is my code

```
<input onClick="check_hidden_radio_email();" type="button" id="emailthis"  value="email cli script" name="emailthis"></input>   
<label onClick="showemailbox();" id="hiddenLabel"><input type="radio" id="hiddenOne" name="hidbutton" value="Yes" <?php if(isset($_POST['hidbutton']) && $_POST['hidbutton'] == 'Yes')  echo ' checked="checked"';?> />

<div id="email-box" style="display:none;" >
<input class="textbox" type="text" id="emailbox" name="emailbox" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['emailbox'])) { echo htmlentities ($_POST['emailbox']); }?>"  placeholder="Enter Your Email ID here" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter Your Email ID here'"/>
<input type="submit" id="send"  value="send" name="send"></input>
</div>
```

and I am using below javascript to check the radio button

```
  function check_hidden_radio_email(){
    hiddenOne.checked = true;
    $('input:radio[name=hidbutton]:checked').click();
}   
  function showemailbox(){
    $('#email-box').slideDown("fast");
}
```

This code is working perfectly in FF and chrome, but in IE, whenever I click the `emailthis` button, it is not checking\clicking the radio button. How can solve this issue with IE

Comment: You're using jQuery AND inline event handlers? Boo

Comment: why are you not setting the `prop("checked",true)` ?

Comment: PS: Why do you use `$('input:radio[name=hidbutton]:checked')` instead of `$('#hiddenOne:checked')`? The `document.getElementById` method is the fastest and most reliable way of selecting DOM elements.

Answer (score 0):

One issue that I see is that the `label` tag is never closed.

```
<label onClick="showemailbox();" id="hiddenLabel">
```